# Not getting the last part of the array correct when running the code. Leetcode 443

Tags: arrays

class Solution {
public int compress(char[] chars) {

```
    String s = "";
    int count = 1;
    s += chars[0];
    
    for(int i=1; i<chars.length; i++){
        
        char curr = chars[i];
        char prev = chars[i-1];
        
        if(curr == prev){
            count++;
        } else{
            if(count>1){
                s += count;
                count = 1;
                
            } 
               s += curr;
        
        }
        
    if(count>1){
                s += count;
                count = 1;
            }

    }
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) chars[i] = s.charAt(i);
    
    return s.length();
}
```

}

I'm getting wrong answer when running it,
Your input
["a","a","b","b","c","c","c"]
Output
["a","2","b","2","c","2","2"]
Expected
["a","2","b","2","c","3"]

Answer (score 0):

the output is wrong because the bottom "if" statement gets executed even when the chars are the same, which is wrong. also, i don't understand why you need the last "for" loop. it doesn't do anything.
the code seems to be inaccurate, please copy the exact code with correct indentation.